# Attribute inheritance on properties fails in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have the following property which has [`Inherited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=netframework-4.8) set to true.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
public class InheritedAttribute : Attribute { }
```

The class DerivedA contains a property which overrides BaseA's virtual property with a `[InheritedAttribute]` tag.

```
public class BaseA
{
    [InheritedAttribute]
    public virtual int prop { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedA : BaseA
{
    public override int prop { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, the attribute is not found on `DerivedA.prop`, thus the attribute has not been inherited to the child property.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(DerivedA).GetProperties()[0];
    // propertyInfo.CustomAttributes is empty
    // propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true) is empty
}
```

If the attribute is placed on a method instead of a property, as seen in the [example code on microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=netframework-4.8), the attribute is inherited as expected, and would be found in the `methodInfo.CustomAttributes`.

Is attribute inheritance simply not allowed on properties? Or am I missing something else entirely?

Comment: Just an idea: Certain attributes of properties are implemented not on Property level, but on the level of there Getters and Setters. Can you check `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod.GetCustomAttributes(true)`. And since this is a Method and Methods should work as described, maybe that's it. (Same for GetSetMethod)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because [`GetCustomAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_GetCustomAttributes_System_Boolean_) method ignores the `inherit` parameter for the properties and events, according to MSDN specifications. Actually, your property has this attribute, you can check it by calling `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` method, as recommended

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(DerivedA).GetProperties()[0];
var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(propertyInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that behavior is strange. But there is a work around like this:

```
 var c = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(InheritedAttribute), true);
```

Which is to specify directly.

Comment: This method ignores `inherit` parameter for properties and events

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it is true for `GetCustomAttributes` not for `GetCustomAttribute` but i prefer your solution because op wants to get the attributes